# Inconsistency of SKScene paused property if present with/without a SKTransition

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

If I present a scene from another scene without a SKTransition the new SKScene is paused.

```
let scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
guard let currentView = view else { return }
currentView.presentScene(scene)
```

However, if I present a scene from another scene with a SKTransition the new SKScene is not paused.

```
let scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
guard let currentView = view else { return }
let reveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.5)
currentView.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
```

From the documentation I understand it should always start as paused by default. Is this a bug on the SDK? A misunderstanding from me and hence this works as designed? There is something that is incorrect on my approach?

Full test code for anybody that wants to try the issue out:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
      print("paused: \(paused)")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
      let scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
      guard let currentView = view else { return }
      let reveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.5)
      currentView.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
      currentView.presentScene(scene)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
      if paused {
        NSLog("update on paused") // Get called if SKScene was presented without transition
      } else {
        NSLog("updating") // Get called if SKScene was presented with transition
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing this on a device? Or the simulator? I checked something similar with XCode 7 + ios9.0 and setting SKTransition's properties pauses(Incoming/Outgoing)Scene to all possible combinations had no effect for me - both outgoing scene and incoming scene get paused (as in, no SKActions run, not specifically scene's paused property being set to true, but the update method does not get called during the animation time of the transition) - in short, appears to be broken because I am 101% sure in ios8 changing the pauses(Incoming/Outgoing)Scene had an effect.

Comment: I have tried this on iOS, tvOS and Mac on Xcode 7 and Xcode 7 beta 2 and  the issue is consistent.